# Node.js server takes a long time to establish connection to database

Tags: node.js, database-connection, connection-pooling, node-mysql

I've built a `Node.js` server that uses the `node-mysql` module to connect to a `MySQL` server. I use the following piece of code:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool( 
    {
    connectionLimit : 15,
    waitForConnections : true,
    host     : 'remotehost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'pass',
    database : 'master',
    }
);
```

This works fine most of the time. However, when I leave the page open for some time (about 30 minutes) and reload it, the time taken for features that require a connection to the database to load is significantly longer. Also, it is only the first connection after the wait that takes a long time to establish. What do you think could be the reason for this?

I use the following syntax to return a connection to the pool after making a query:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM logtable", function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
connection.release();
```

Comment: You should only call `connection.release();` inside your callback since that is where you know the query is finished, not immediately following the `query()` since it is asynchronous and non-blocking.

Comment: @mscdex: That's how I was doing it earlier. But this code produces the same result too. This can't be the reason for the latency right?